# MVC3 Dynamic routing multiple urls to single controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

Essentially,  I am looking to acheive something like:

website.com/{customerName}/SingleController/actions/

Where SingleController is a controller which serves up pages based on the database lookup for {customerName} and for example, might swap a CSS file or something.  How can I set a route to map {customerName} as a wildcard?  It might seem backwards to not have the controller first, but the primary reason for this setup would be to have a customer's distinct page show up at

http://website.com/{customerName}.

Answer (score 0):

Typical example encapsulated using register routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            null,                                           // Route name
            "{customerName}/SingleController/actions",                            // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "SingleController", action = "actions" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```